# Django SQLite view returns Empty Queryset []

Tags: python, django, sqlite, sql-view

Hi I'm new to Django / SQLite and i'm getting an empty qurty set when i read from a view.
Other tables and views that i've created are behaving normally.
when i use DB Browser for SQLite, I can see the data is there.

```
#nmsdb_app.models.py
class V_WSW_Table_People_Chooser(models.Model):
    Username = models.CharField(max_length=31)
    Record_ID = models.CharField(max_length=11)
    Display_Text = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Username

    #stop django from trying to treat sql views as tables
    class Meta:
        managed = False
```

python manage.py shell:

```
from nmsdb_app.models import V_WSW_Table_People_Chooser
V_WSW_Table_People_Chooser.objects.all()
<QuerySet []>
```

to make the view on the SQLite server:
 1. do the model
 2. makemigrations
 3. migrate
 4. drop the SQLIte table and replace with the view
 5. add managed = False to the model class

I've tried the Record_ID field as Text and Integer but it makes no difference.
When i use DB Browser for SQLite, the view data appears correctly.
Any help received with thanks.

Comment: Aside: _please_ avoid names like `V_WSW_Table_People_Chooser` in Python. Unlike many other programming language communities there's a lot of agreement on Python style. Start by reviewing [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). Classes should generally use `CamelCase` and properties, like `Username` and `Display_Text` here, should use `snake_case` (note that all characters are lowercase).

Comment: Where is `UserManager` imported from? Are you using a custom user model, or a custom manager?

Comment: UserManager was added while trying another suggestion - will remove as it didn't make sense to me.

Comment: I'm also confused as to why you'd create a model, generate a migration from it, run the migration, then drop the table and add `managed=False`. When you say "view" here, do you literally mean a [view in SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createview.html)? What is the view called? Does it exactly match the name of the table that Django created?

Comment: hi chris, as the title says, i'm having trouble with an SQLite View. I created the model as an empty table 1st, to make sure that the model name and fields exactly matched the the SQLView that I replaced it with.
it also makes sure that the migration changes get recorded in git.

Comment: …but why do you want the migration to be recorded if you're going to throw it away and create the view manually? The whole point of `managed=False` is to _prevent_ Django from managing the table lifecycle. Anyway, please see what value `V_WSW_Table_People_Chooser._meta.db_table` has. Does it _precisely_ match the name of your database view?